# Let $\phi$ be symmetric. Simplify:$\bigg(\forall x \in M:\exists y \in M: \phi(x,y)\bigg)\land \bigg(\forall y \in M:\exists x \in M: \phi(x,y)\bigg)$

Tags: logic

Let $\phi $ be symmetric. Is there a more concise equivalent statement for 
$$
\bigg(\forall x \in M:\exists y \in M: \phi(x,y)\bigg)\land \bigg(\forall y \in M:\exists x \in M: \phi(x,y)\bigg)
$$

A use of the statement would be the following:

Let $f(x)= Ax$, where $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, x\in\mathbb{C}^n$.

Then, if $A$ is regular, a substitued version of the above formula holds:
$$
F:=\bigg(\forall x \in \mathbb{C}^n:\exists y \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x)=y\bigg)\land \bigg(\forall y \in \mathbb{C}^n:\exists x \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x)=y\bigg)
$$

And it basically says the following: 
If we want to check a statement $\forall x\in\mathbb C^n:\psi(f(x))$, then, if $F$ holds, we have 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb C^n:\psi(f(x)) \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, \forall x\in\mathbb C^n:\psi(x)$$

Comment: In your example, $\phi(x,y):f(x)=y$ is not symmetric-- if $x,y$ switched meaning changes.

Comment: If I set $S := \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{ C}^{n\times n}\mid f(x)=y\}$, then doesn't the first part $\bigg(\forall x \in \mathbb{C}^n:\exists y \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x)=y\bigg)$ basically say that for every $x$ there's a tuple $(x,y)\in S$; While the second part says that for every $y$ there's a tuple $(x,y)\in S$?

Comment: Don't quite follow that... you could just say both to be sure.

Comment: I mean that $\bigg(\forall x \in \mathbb{C}^n:\exists y \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x)=y\bigg)$ says that for every $x$ there's a tuple $(x,y)\in S$, and that $\bigg(\forall y \in \mathbb{C}^n:\exists x \in \mathbb{C}^n: f(x)=y\bigg)$ says that for every $y$ there's a tuple $(x,y)\in S$.

Comment: hmm-- will think about that and respond if I can say something. Also what is meaning of your "symmetric" assumption? That (x,y) in S iff (y,x) in S? [If so yes, equivalent].

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry for the delayed response. Symmetric is supposed to mean, that if you fix $x,y$, then $\phi(x,y) $ and $\phi(y,x)$ always have the same truth-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drop one of the conjuncts. Your first conjunct is $\forall x\in M.\exists y\in M.\phi(x,y)$. By symmetry, this is equivalent to $\forall x\in M.\exists y\in M.\phi(y,x)$. Then you just rename variables to get $\forall y\in M.\exists x\in M.\phi(x,y)$ which is just your second conjunct.

I'm not sure what you mean by "regular" here. I think you just mean invertible. If so, then, as coffeemath states, the relation you give is not necessarily symmetric. If $f(x)=y$ is a symmetric relation, then that means if $f$ sends $\mathbf u$ to $\mathbf v$ then $f(\mathbf v)$ needs to be $\mathbf u$. A permutation matrix that rotates $3$ or more vectors won't satisfy this. In fact, we would need $f$ to be self-inverse for this to be true, i.e. $f\circ f = id$ or, equivalently for this example, $A^2=1$.